# How to remove extra one legend from High Charts- Bar chart (multiple & stacked)

Tags: highcharts, stackedbarseries

I have stacked columns for 103 and 104. so either I have to show all 103 colors in the legend or remove the second 103 legend. How can we achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can hide the legend item by disabling `showInLegend` option or by linking it to other by `linkedTo`.

---

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.showInLegend

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.linkedTo